# SQL Server Left and Right Outer Join

Tags: sql-server, left-join

Below query works fine in PL/Sql but I want to run in MS Sql Server.. Can anyone help me pls.

```
SELECT  ARM_KEYID, ARD_KEYID, FCT_FACTORYID, FCT_NAME, AUC_AUDITTYPEID, ATM_DESCRIPT,   
      LIN_LINEID, LIN_DESCRIPTION, CEL_CELLID, CEL_DESCRIPTION,ARM_EMPID,
      AUDITOR.EMP_NAME,   ARM_REPDATE, AUC_WEEKNO,AUC_FROMDATE, AUC_TILLDATE, 
      (SELECT OPD_DESCRIPT 
      FROM OPERATIONSDETAILS OPD 
      WHERE OPD.OPD_KEYID = OPDDETAILS.OPD_PARENTID),
      OPD_OPNO, OPD_DESCRIPT ,  CLD_OPNO, CLD_DESCRIPT, 
      ALM_KEYID,DECODE(ALD_PRIORITY,'H','High','M','Medium','L','Low') ALD_PRIORITY, 
      ARD_FEEDBACK,ARD_NCCLASSIFICATION,ALD_NCACTION,OWNER.EMP_NAME, 
      dpt_description  ,  ALD_TARGETDATE,  COMPLETED.EMP_NAME, ALD_COMPLETIONDATE,
      ALD_COMPREMARKS ,  DECODE(ALD_STATUS,'Y',ROUND(ALD_COMPLETIONDATE-ALD_TIMESTAMP),
      ROUND(SYSDATE-ALD_TIMESTAMP)) AS PENDING_DAYS,  
      DECODE(ALD_STATUS,'Y','COMPLETED','N','PENDING') AS LAD_STATUS  
FROM       AUDITREPORTMASTER, AUDITREPORTDETAILS,   CHECKLISTDETAILS, AUDITCALENDAR,   OPERATIONSMASTER, 
      OPERATIONSDETAILS OPDDETAILS, ACTIONLISTMASTER, ACTIONLISTDETAILS,   
      AUDITTYPEMASTER, CELLMASTER, EMPLOYEEMASTER AUDITOR, EMPLOYEEMASTER 
      OWNER, EMPLOYEEMASTER COMPLETED ,  FACTORYMASTER,LINEMASTER , departmentmaster   
WHERE   ARD_NCSTATUS = 'N' 
      AND ARD_RECNO ='1' 
      AND AUC_ACTIVE='Y' 
      AND ARM_KEYID = ARD_MASTERID 
      AND CLD_KEYID = ARD_CKDETAILID  
      AND AUC_KEYID = ARM_CALENDARID  
      AND AUC_OPDKEYID = OPD_KEYID  
      AND OPM_KEYID = OPD_OPMASTERID 
      AND ATM_KEYID = AUC_AUDITTYPEID  
      AND CEL_CELLID = AUC_LINEID 
      AND LIN_LINEID = AUC_SECTIONID  
      AND ARM_EMPID = AUDITOR.EMP_EMPLOYEEID 
      AND ALD_OWNER = OWNER.EMP_EMPLOYEEID (+) 
      AND DPT_DEPARTMENTID(+) = OWNER.emp_departmentid   
      AND ALD_COMPLETEDBY = COMPLETED.EMP_EMPLOYEEID (+)  
      AND FCT_FACTORYID = AUC_FACTORYID  
      AND ALD_AUDITDETAILID (+) = ARD_KEYID 
      AND ALM_KEYID (+) = ALD_MASTERID 
      AND ALD_STATUS  IS NULL  AND ARM_ACTIVE ='Y' AND AUC_AUDITTYPEID = 'ATM/01' 
ORDER BY FCT_FACTORYID, OPM_AUDITTYPEID, CEL_CELLID,ARM_REPDATE;
```

Comment: You query even in it's current edited form is not readable and thus question is likely to distract readers even before reading the post. Please consider formatting of high importance when asking questions in future.

Answer (score 0):

If you had better formatting and more explicit join syntax and naming convention instead of the implicit joins and naming it would make the code much more readable and re-writable.Your code should look something like this.

Note: This is not a working version of the code because i have had to make a lot of assumptions because of the missing explicit column/table naming, but you get the idea on what needs to be done.

```
SELECT  ARM_KEYID, 
        ARD_KEYID, 
        FCT_FACTORYID, 
        FCT_NAME, 
        AUC_AUDITTYPEID, 
        ATM_DESCRIPT,   
        LIN_LINEID, 
        LIN_DESCRIPTION, 
        CEL_CELLID, 
        CEL_DESCRIPTION,
        ARM_EMPID,
        AUDITOR.EMP_NAME,   
        ARM_REPDATE, 
        AUC_WEEKNO,
        AUC_FROMDATE, 
        AUC_TILLDATE, 
        OPD.OPD_DESCRIPT,
        OPD_OPNO, 
        OPD_DESCRIPT,  
        CLD_OPNO, 
        CLD_DESCRIPT, 
        ALM_KEYID,
          CASE   
            WHEN ALD_PRIORITY='H' THEN 'High'
            WHEN ALD_PRIORITY='M' THEN 'Medium'
            WHEN ALD_PRIORITY='L' THEN 'Low'
          END AS ALD_PRIORITY,
        ARD_FEEDBACK,
        ARD_NCCLASSIFICATION,
        ALD_NCACTION,
        OWNER.EMP_NAME, 
        dpt_description,  
        ALD_TARGETDATE,  
        COMPLETED.EMP_NAME, 
        ALD_COMPLETIONDATE,
        ALD_COMPREMARKS,
        CASE     
            WHEN ALD_STATUS='Y' THEN ROUND(ALD_COMPLETIONDATE-ALD_TIMESTAMP,ROUND(SYSDATE-ALD_TIMESTAMP,1)) --ROUND NEEDS ATLEAST 2 ATTRIBUTES
          END AS PENDING_DAYS,
        CASE     
            WHEN ALD_STATUS='Y' THEN 'COMPLETED'
            WHEN ALD_STATUS='N' THEN 'PENDING'
          END AS LAD_STATUS,
FROM    AUDITREPORTMASTER ARM 
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN OWNER ON ARM.ALD_OWNER = OWNER.EMP_EMPLOYEEID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ARM.DPT_DEPARTMENTID = OWNER.emp_departmentid  
        JOIN EMPLOYEEMASTER AUDITOR ON ARM.ARM_EMPID = AUDITOR.EMP_EMPLOYEEID
        JOIN AUDITREPORTDETAILS ARD ON
        ARM.ARM_KEYID = ARD.ARD_MASTERID
        -- Add all the other joins and if the (+) is before the = its left outer join else its right outer join
WHERE ARD_NCSTATUS = 'N' 
      AND ARD_RECNO ='1' 
      AND AUC_ACTIVE='Y' 
      AND ALD_STATUS  IS NULL  
      AND ARM_ACTIVE ='Y' 
      AND AUC_AUDITTYPEID = 'ATM/01' 
ORDER BY FCT_FACTORYID, OPM_AUDITTYPEID, CEL_CELLID,ARM_REPDATE;
```

Comment: Suppose I want to  add 3-4 different  tables Like AuditCalender,AuditReportDetails,LineMaster etc as join in the left side of the expression then how will I proceed..

Comment: You will need to add it exactly the same way as the JOIN AUDITREPORTDETAIL mentioned above. But you will need to identify what key columns you need to join against in each table. for example: AuditReportDetail joins on the ard_masterid to arm_keyid in the AuditReportMaster table and so on. You will have to have an understanding of the relationship or will need a ER diagram as a reference to write the joins.